# Storm error: connection attempt 86 to Netty-Client

Tags: apache-storm

I am always getting following error:

> [ERROR] connection attempt 86 to Netty-Client-/202.162.247.10:6731 failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /202.162.247.10:6731

Why is this happening?
I tried and googled multiple times but found no solution.

Comment: Post some code and add some more useful tags to the question so that more users can reach this post.

Comment: I have the same issue, have a look at this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1382ffrfw1