# Connection refused error in worker logs - apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

I see the below error in worker logs, it happens almost every milliseconds, but the cluster is running fine, I wanted to know what does these error mean and any idea on why this would occur.

This happens on all the worker nodes

2016-05-12T15:32:53.514-0500 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 3 to Netty-Client-xxxxx.hq.abc.com/xx.xx.xxx.xx:6700 failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: xxxxx.hq.abc.com/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:6700

And after some time i see this
2016-05-12T15:44:25.940-0500 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] discarding 1 messages because the Netty client to Netty-Client-xxxxx.hq.abc.com/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:6700 is being closed

Comment: I have the same issue, have a look at this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1382ffrfw1

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648103/storm-error-connection-attempt-86-to-netty-client

Comment: No answers on the bug yet, anyone else seen this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling forever with this problem, I found that setting storm.local.hostname property in the storm.yaml file solved the issue for me. On my laptop, I set storm.zookeeper.servers, nimbus.host and storm.local.hostname all to "localhost".

I am using version 0.10.2 of storm.