# Getting Netty client related error in storm topology and worker restarting

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

```
Version Info: 
   "org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.2.1" 
   "org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka-client" % "1.2.1"
```

I have a storm Topology with 3 bolts(A,B,C), Where the middle bolt takes around 450ms mean time and other two bolts takes less than 1ms.

I am running topology with following parallelism hint values on two machines:

```
A: 4 
B: 700
C: 10
```

I am getting following error after few minutes of topology starting:

in worker log:

> 2018-07-04T20:16:28.835+05:30 Client [ERROR] discarding 7 messages because the Netty client to Netty-Client-/ip:6700 is being closed

in supervisor logs:

```
2018-07-04 20:16:29.468 o.a.s.d.s.BasicContainer [INFO] Worker Process 32bc11c0-a1d0-4593-a91a-3ff788ea041a exited with code: 20

2018-07-04 20:16:31.592 o.a.s.d.s.Slot [WARN] SLOT 6700: main process has exited

2018-07-04 20:16:31.592 o.a.s.d.s.Container [INFO] Killing 2825cbe9-aedd-4f10-a796-4f9dc30ae72f:32bc11c0-a1d0-4593-a91a-3ff788ea041a

2018-07-04 20:16:31.600 o.a.s.u.Utils [INFO] Error when trying to kill 7422. Process is probably already dead.

2018-07-04 20:16:32.600 o.a.s.d.s.Slot [INFO] STATE RUNNING msInState: 391195 topo:myTopo-1-1530715184 worker:32bc11c0-a1d0-4593-a91a-3ff788ea041a -> KILL_AND_RELAUNCH msInState: 0 topo:myTopo-1-1530715184 worker:32bc11c0-a1d0-4593-a91a-3ff788ea041a

2018-07-04 20:16:32.600 o.a.s.d.s.Container [INFO] GET worker-user for 32bc11c0-a1d0-4593-a91a-3ff788ea041a
```

I see similar question asked [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5116/is-anyone-else-having-errors-with-netty-using-stor.html) and [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201702.mbox/%3C000d01d2836d$0478b860$0d6a2920$@trinitymobility.com%3E), I have few queries related to this:

1. Why is this error coming and how to resolve?
2. How to get more debug information from Storm, I have already set `conf.setDebug(true)`
3. Is there some limitation/guidelines around how much parallelism factor os OK for a bolt on n number of machines?

### Edit:

Logs for `strace -fp PID -e trace=read,write,network,signal,ipc` in [gist](https://gist.github.com/mimani/378c3dd86a267e6a2eba4b378fe62b9e). Some relevant looking part is when above thing happends, but however I see such `SIGSEGV` many places in strace output :

```
[pid 23635] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7f83af6f1180} ---
[pid 23549] <... read resumed> "PK\3\4\n\0\0\0\10\0\364J\336F\222'\202\312\310\2\0\0\16\5\0\0\36\0\0\0", 30) = 30
[pid 23654] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7f83af6f1f80} ---
[pid 23549] read(23, "\235TmW\22A\24~\6\224\227u\vE4\255,JR\300WP\322\0245TH\23\313\3j\347"..., 712) = 712
[pid 23654] rt_sigreturn({mask=[QUIT]}) = 140203560738688
[pid 23635] rt_sigreturn({mask=[QUIT]}) = 140203560735104
```

strace output of worker process is [here](https://gist.github.com/mimani/eb7be2b18909cc18087c4e640677711a), relevant looking logs here:

```
[pid 24435] recvfrom(291, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: a"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 544
[pid 23473] write(3, "Heap\n garbage-first heap   total"..., 347) = 347
[pid 24434] +++ exited with 20 +++
[pid 24405] +++ exited with 20 +++
[pid 24435] +++ exited with 20 +++
[pid 24427] +++ exited with 20 +++
```

### Edit 2:

There is this question as well: [Connection refused error in worker logs - apache storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197419/connection-refused-error-in-worker-logs-apache-storm) : as par it's answer not setting `storm.local.hostname` might cause it, but it is already set for me.

There is another bug filed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1382ffrfw1) having similar netty error, which is also still unresolved.